# Should I install Ubuntu into Hard Disk for installing Java or Hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

I am a beginner in Ubuntu. I want to install Hadoop and Sun Java. After downloading, I have written Ubuntu 12.10 to a DVD. I am also able to boot from the CD. I am currently able to boot from Ubuntu DVD and I do not want to install Ubuntu into Hard Disk to save space. I want to know whether I need to install Ubuntu operating system into my Hard Disk to install Java 6 or hadoop on Ubuntu.?

I have a 64 bit laptop which is currently running on Windows 7 home.

Comment: You can always use a virtual machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanted to get a look at Ubuntu / Hadoop then it would work as long as it was booted and running. If you wanted to preserve the ability to boot from the DVD / ISO and not install then you could create a dedicated drive that you could mount inside Ubuntu once booted that had your Hadoop install and you would then preserve the Hadoop install and whatever else you had on that mount.

Ubuntu will come up with OpenJDK 6 or at least some level of Java support depending on the Ubuntu Release.

You could also use VirtualBox but that requires diskspace

Lastly, you could try [Pendrive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) which allows you to run off a USB Drive.

Comment: Thank you apesa for your time and answer.

Comment: I added another option that I remembered later which may be something you'd like. Check my edited answer